# vue-cli devServer proxy bypass

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack-dev-server, vue-cli-3

I would like Vue CLI's dev server to return a string when a specific URL is fetched. For this, I wanted to use `webpack dev-server`'s `bypass` option. ([webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy))

I tried this:

```js
devServer: {
    proxy: {
        '/something': {
            bypass: (req, res) => res.send(process.env.SOMETHING),
        }
    }
}
```

This causes an error: `When proxy in package.json is an object, each context object must have a target property specified as a url string`.

I don't need a `target` option (like in [this example](https://linguinecode.com/post/webpack-dev-server-proxy-api-calls-react))

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`devServer.proxy` isn't appropriate for this. Instead, add your route in [`devServer.before`](https://web.archive.org/web/20210812150620/https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverbefore) in Webpack 4 (used in Vue CLI 4):

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    before(app) {
      app.get('/something', (req, res) => res.send(process.env.SOMETHING))
    }
  }
}
```

...or [`devServer.onBeforeSetupMiddleware`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserveronbeforesetupmiddleware) in Webpack 5 (used in Vue CLI 5):

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    onBeforeSetupMiddleware(server) {
      server.app.get('/something', (req, res) => res.send(process.env.SOMETHING))
    }
  }
}
```