# vite dev server execute middleware before all other middleware

Tags: vue-cli, vite

With vue-cli it was possible to configure webpack [devServer.before](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverbefore) function like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64346635/2112538):

```js
devServer: {
    before(app) {
      app.get('/apiUrl', (req, res) => res.send(process.env.API_URL))
    }
  },
```

How is it possible to configure [Vite dev server](https://vitejs.dev/config/#server-options) to obtain the same behavior?

(I tried with the `proxy` option but it does not work.)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this github issue](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/1930),  environment variables are not accessible in file `vite.config.js` (neither in `vite.config.ts`). However, the discussion in this issue also mentions a workaround that you can use in this file:

```
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig(({mode}) => {
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd());
  return {
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ],
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '^/apiUrl': {
        target: env.VITE_API_TARGET,
        changeOrigin: true,
      }
    }
  },
}
})
```

Note that the variable name must start with `VITE_` for this to work.